# Why am i getting this error (java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind) even after closing the socket?

Tags: java

**What i'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to send 2 files over a socket connection where each file is getting divided into 4 parts and then transmitted using 4 ports (one port for each part).

I'm able to send one file completely with zero issues but facing issue when the second file is ready to be sent.

**Here's some of the code:**

**Sender.java**

```
public void send() throws InterruptedException {
        // runs two times in total
        for (File f : files) {
            long allowedReadLength = f.length() / (4);
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int finalI = i;
                es.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            threadTask(finalI, f.getName(), new RandomAccessFile(f, "r"), allowedReadLength, allowedReadLength * finalI, ip, portArray[finalI]);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            es.shutdown();
            es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
    }


//  int[] portArray = {9999,9998,9997,9996};
private void threadTask(int i, String fileName, RandomAccessFile raf, long allowedReadLength, long seekPosition, String ip, int port) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
            if (s.isConnected()) {
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
               
                // some logic
                
                bos.close();
                raf.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Receiver.java**

```
void startListening() throws InterruptedException {
        int[] ports = {9999,9998,9997,9996};
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                int finalJ = j;
                es.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            threadTask(new ServerSocket(ports[finalJ]).accept());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            es.shutdown();
            es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
    }

private void threadTask(Socket s) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            
            // some logic

            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is what i'm getting:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
    at com.tsc.whsft.transfer.Receiver$1.run(Receiver.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
    at com.tsc.whsft.transfer.Receiver$1.run(Receiver.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
    at com.tsc.whsft.transfer.Receiver$1.run(Receiver.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
    at com.tsc.whsft.transfer.Receiver$1.run(Receiver.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The problem occurs when the outer for loop runs for the second time in **Receiver.java**.

Now what i wanted to ask is , isn't the socket supposed to be closed when **BufferedInputStream** is closed in the receiver ?

If it is so then why am i still getting this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you are closing the socket created by statement `new ServerSocket(ports[finalJ]).accept()`, while the server sockets are still bound to those 4 ports, so when `new ServerSocket(ports[finalJ])` executes (4 times) on the second iteration, it drops the error.

You need to instantiate 4 server sockets once, at the beginning of `startListening()` method, and use "accept" on them, without "new":

```
void startListening() {   
 int[] ports = ...   
 ServerSocket[] ssockets = new ServerSocket[ports.length];  
 for (int k=0; k < ports.length; k++)
    ssockets[k] = new ServerSocket (ports[k]);  

...
try
{
threadTask(ssockets[finalJ].accept());
}
...

}//end method
```

PS. unclear why you reassign i and j to finalI and finalJ instead of using i and j themselves

Comment: Because of this:  java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @user10825524 aha I guess I need to re-read some language aspects, many small facts that are easy to forget. Was writing from my phone so didn't have a chance to compile it